# Conditional Laravel Eloquent relation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table `note` with `id, note, type_id, about_id`. Here the `type_id` refers to the different type like `task(601), discussion (602), images (603),` etc. And `about_id` refers to the id of respected type table.

```
$note = Notes::with('tasks')->with('discussion')->with('images')->get();
```

This returned notes with all the `->with()` table value. How can I get the values of related table according to the `type_id`. I tried

```
$note=Notes::where('deleted_at', null);
$note=$note->WhereHas('tasks', function($q) use($note)
{
    $note->Where('type_id',601);
})->get();
```

Is it possible to get only related tables value using eloquent.

Comment: I think you should prefer join

Comment: "get only related tables value" .. not sure what that means

Comment: @lagbox I mean get values from the table according to `type_id` . If its 601 get values from task, if 602 get from discussion and so on.

Comment: so really you are trying to make some morph type relation?  ...  type (other table) type_id (id on that table)  ?

Comment: @lagbox Thanks for pointing it out. I am looking into it right now. I guess this will work.

Comment: @lagbox I solved it using Polymorphic Relations.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Use($note)` unnecessary , Remove this and use `$q` instead

```
   $note = Notes::where('deleted_at', null)
   ->whereHas('tasks', function($q){ 
        $q->where('type_id',601); 
   })->get();
```

Also include `->with('tasks')` if you want get all related `tasks`